# Split 4 Track WAV file into 2 stereo WAV files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-encoding

The audio recorder my friend has can record 4 tracks at the same time, but unfortunately i records into a 4-track WAV file.

The problem i have is that the DAW i use only accepts mono or stereo WAV files.

So i would like to split the 4-track files into 2 stereo-wav files, without changing any properties of the file ( keep same bitdepth and bitrate ).

Is there an easy way to do it? Perhaps using ffmpeg or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the '4 tracks' are channels of a WAV. There is an easy way to extract each channel from WAV files. Using `sox` you can try this:

```
sox infile.wav outfile.1.wav remix 1
sox infile.wav outfile.2.wav remix 2
sox infile.wav outfile.3.wav remix 3
sox infile.wav outfile.4.wav remix 4
```

Comment: yes, by "tracks" i meant, channels of a wave!